# Bootstrap styling not being applied to Rails page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems

I'm new to Rails, so have been following an online video tutorial building a project.

I've been trying to add Bootstrap, but even after

1. Adding the Gem,
2. Doing a bundle install,
3. Restarting the mysql server, and
4. Adding the scss @bootsrap import to the application.css.scss file,

It's still not pulling though to my index page.

Is there something I'm missing?

**Here's my application.css.scss**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 */
// Custom bootstrap variables must be set or imported before bootstrap itself.
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

**Here's my gem file:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'simple_form', '>= 3.2.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you show us your `application.css`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add in your `application.html.erb`

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

And add in your `application.css`

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import 'bootstrap/theme';
```

Comment: Thanks!  

I had added 'default' in place of 'application'.

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>` 

Changed this back and uncommented out the application.js _require_ and it's all working now.  Thanks!